# Has Apple ditched the enter key symbol in their mac devices international keyboard?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, keyboard

The <kbd>return</kbd> key in Apple's keyboard layout has two functions, the <kbd>return</kbd> key `↩`; and the <kbd>enter</kbd> key `⌤` (which is produced by <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>).

However, the new Macbooks has no `⌤` symbol engraved on keyboard! Does that means it's not supported anymore? I know it sounds silly but I use the <kbd>return</kbd>/<kbd>enter</kbd> combinations a lot in my apps?

Appreciate any answer because I want to upgrade and not sure if the <kbd>enter</kbd> key is not supported or just missed in keyboard?

Comment: As far as I know, the layout remains engraved with both symbols (per [Apple's website](https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/keyboards/arabic_notebook.png)); if that's changed, do you have a photo of it?

Comment: That is what i've read in the documentation, but since the 2017/2018 models many changes happened to the keyboard layout like the printed Arabic commands above the dead keys (`الهروب`,`الرجوع`,`التحكم`,`العالي`, ...etc) that's an image to the exact model i'm thinking of buying [link] https://imgur.com/a/0NmI3In

Comment: Hrm, okay. Can't confirm 100%, but for a US keyboard set to the Arabic layout, I can confirm that return/enter functions as normal once the fn key is pressed. [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL097.gif)

Comment: That is actually enough for me since i guess there is not much of a difference between the US and international layout. Sadly there is no way to confirm 100%.

Comment: Cool! If you'd like I'm happy to post that as an answer so you can accept it and have the question closed.

Comment: Okey, fair enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't confirm 100% since I don't have a keyboard with an Arabic physical layout on hand, but for a US keyboard on a 2018 tMBP set to the Arabic layout, I can confirm that return/enter functions as normal once the fn key is pressed.

[image]

Comment: Nice animation!